# pgfplots: patch diagram, change color of individual rectangles

Tags: pgfplots

**Update:** Follow-up question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571816).

---

- I want to create a "patchwork" diagram with [`pgfplots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?).
- I use `patch plots`, see "Chapter 4.6.13 Patch Plots".
- I do *not* have experience with 3D plots (surf, mesh etc.).
- **Question:** I want to assign rectangle with a custom color, is that possible?
- Alternatively, how can I influence the color (`point meta`) when I use `coordinates` like in the MWE?

> **Background:** I want to give bigger rectangles a more "important" color than small rectangles, similar (not the same) to the visualization of
> https://windirstat.net/ or http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/ (see
> [screenshot](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/screen-shots/kdirstat-main.png)).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title = Just a Title,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 100,
    colormap/blackwhite, % Just for testing
]
\addplot [
    patch,
    patch type = rectangle,
    ] coordinates {
        (0,0) (30,0) (30,12) (0,12)
        (0,12) (30,12) (30,18) (0,18)
        (30,0) (50,0) (50,12) (30,12)
        (30,12) (50,12) (50,18) (30,18)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `patchplots` library. This is more or less the example from p. 472 adapted to your use case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
    title = Just a Title]
\addplot [table/row sep=\\,
    patch,
    patch type=polygon,
    vertex count=4,
    patch table with point meta={
            % pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 cdata
            0 1 2 3 2\\
            2 3 5 4 1.5\\
            1 6 7 2 3\\
            2 7 8 4 4\\},
    ] table {
        x y z\\
        0 0 0\\%0
        30 0 0\\%1
        30 12 0\\%2
        0 12 0\\%3
        30 18 0\\%4
        0 18 0\\%5
        50 0 0\\%6
        50 12 0\\%7
        50 18 0\\%8
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above accesses the colors from the default color map, which is `hot`. You can define your own so that you know what each color is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title = Just a Title]
\addplot [table/row sep=\\,
    patch,
    patch type=polygon,
    vertex count=4,
    colormap={custom}{
        color(1)=(blue)
        color(2)=(green)
        color(3)=(orange)
        color(4)=(red)
    },
    patch table with point meta={
            % pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4 cdata
            0 1 2 3 1\\
            2 3 5 4 2\\
            1 6 7 2 3\\
            2 7 8 4 4\\},
    ] table {
        x y\\
        0 0\\%0
        30 0\\%1
        30 12\\%2
        0 12\\%3
        30 18\\%4
        0 18\\%5
        50 0\\%6
        50 12\\%7
        50 18\\%8
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Thx! Can you explain how the color relate to your code?

Comment: (I go offline now, I am in San Francisco tome zone, will reply tomorrow, I really appreciate your help).

Comment: Hello again, just so that I know: Do you think to consider my question in the comment?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Oh, my bad. Sorry! I added a second version in which it is clear what which color is, e.g. `color(1)=(blue)` means that `1` gets translated to `blue`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept your answer. In order to get a diagram similar to http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/screen-shots/kdirstat-main.png, do you think, that this is the right approach? Or should I ask another question where I ask for the right approach?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It really depends on how you want to generate the diagram, i.e. what the input is. It appears possible to achieve something of that sort with `patch table with individual point meta`, see the second example on p. 179 of pgfplots v1.17. also believe that it is possible to generate the input very automatically with `pgfplotstable` to generate the table that you either feed into `pgfplots` or just Ti*k*Z. However, I also think that it makes sense to ask a separate question on this, in which you specify the input data and the desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I posted a follow-up question as discussed (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571816), just FYI.

Comment: (You are not by any chance the reincarnation of a previous user?)