# pgfplots: Best way to draw a "patchwork" diagram

Tags: pgfplots

### Update / Remark

After I got a hint in the chat I also asked the question [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1518) (outside of https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and got an alternative approach.

---

- This is a follow-up question of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571629).
- I want to draw a diagram as shown in the hand drawing.
- The idea is to provide a table with `x`, `y`, `color` and a `label` for each rectangle.

### Input

The input could look similar to the following. These are just generic proposals.

**Version 1 (Absolute Values)**

```
x    y    color    label
% First Column
10   5    green    Labelx1y1
10   15   green    Labelx1y2
10   20   green    Labelx1y3
% Second Column
18   5    green    Labelx2y1
18   15   green    Labelx2y2
18   20   green    Labelx2y3
% Third Column
25   5    green    Labelx3y1
25   15   green    Labelx3y2
25   20   red      Labelx3y3 % RED rectangle
```

**Version 1 (Relative Values)**

In this example, the `x`-values and `y`-values are added.

```
x    y    color    label
% First Column
10   5    green    Labelx1y1
10   10   green    Labelx1y2
10   5    green    Labelx1y3
% Second Column
8   5    green    Labelx2y1
8   10   green    Labelx2y2
8   5    green    Labelx2y3
% Third Column
7   5    green    Labelx3y1
7   10   green    Labelx3y2
7   5    red      Labelx3y3 % RED rectangle
```

### Output

[image]

### Main Question and Remarks

- **Question:** Does this diagram type has a name?
- **Main Question:** What would be a clever way to achieve this?
- **Remark:** I would prefer to use `pgfplots`.
- **Remark:** I am not married to a specific input format - I generate the data myself (Matlab, Python, Excel) and can therefore influence it.

Comment: For this task I think a matrix plot will be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very basic option. Use `pgfplotstable` and plain Ti*k*Z to convert the data in a plot. Since it is very basic, it may be easy to customize. The prize that you have to pay is that you need to fix some things by hand in

```
x=3mm,y=3mm,declare function={nrows=3;}
```

which sets the units and the number of rows. (In all fairness, also in some `pgfplots` scenarios you have to set the number of rows or columns explicitly.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3mm,y=3mm,declare function={nrows=3;}]
\pgfplotstableread{%
x    y    color    label
% First Column
10   5    green    Labelx1y1
10   15   green    Labelx1y2
10   20   green    Labelx1y3
% Second Column
18   5    green    Labelx2y1
18   15   green    Labelx2y2
18   20   green    Labelx2y3
% Third Column
25   5    green    Labelx3y1
25   15   green    Labelx3y2
25   20   red      Labelx3y3
}\dataA
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\dataA}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}%
\edef\lastx{0}%
\edef\lasty{0}%
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped\X in{0,...,\numrows} {%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{x}\of\dataA
\let\x\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{y}\of\dataA
\let\y\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{color}\of\dataA
\let\mycolor\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{label}\of\dataA
\let\mylabel\pgfplotsretval
\draw[fill=\mycolor] (\lastx,\lasty) rectangle (\x,\y) node[midway]{\mylabel};
\let\lasty\y
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{Mod(\X+nrows+1,nrows)}%
\ifnum\itest=0\relax
\edef\lasty{0}%
\let\lastx\x
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can actually embed this into `pgfplots`. There is a small issue regarding the expansion, hence the `\edef` and `\noexpand` trickery (see the discussion on p. 545 of the pgfplots manual v1.17).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={nrows=3;}]
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,title=Random title]
\pgfplotstableread{%
x    y    color    label
% First Column
10   5    green    Labelx1y1
10   15   green    Labelx1y2
10   20   green    Labelx1y3
% Second Column
18   5    green    Labelx2y1
18   15   green    Labelx2y2
18   20   green    Labelx2y3
% Third Column
25   5    green    Labelx3y1
25   15   green    Labelx3y2
25   20   red      Labelx3y3
}\dataA
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\dataA}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}%
\edef\lastx{0}%
\edef\lasty{0}%
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped\X in{0,...,\numrows} {%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{x}\of\dataA
\let\x\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{y}\of\dataA
\let\y\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{color}\of\dataA
\let\mycolor\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\X}{label}\of\dataA
\let\mylabel\pgfplotsretval
\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[fill=\mycolor] coordinates {(\lastx,\lasty) (\lastx,\y)
(\x,\y) (\x,\lasty) (\lastx,\lasty)};
\noexpand\path (\lastx,\lasty) rectangle (\x,\y) node[midway]{\mylabel};}
\temp
\let\lasty\y
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{Mod(\X+nrows+1,nrows)}%
\ifnum\itest=0\relax
\edef\lasty{0}%
\let\lastx\x
\fi
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Thanks a lot! I wait and see if maybe a pgfplots solution is also proposed. The benefit of a pgfplots solution to me would be that I have more previous experience with that (e. g. having axes and title "out of the box" etc.).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I totally agree. Was playing a bit with `patch plots` and `matrix plots` but was not able to get what I want easily. Adding a title is not too difficult but if you use `pgfplots` for all other plots it will be cumbersome to reproduce all aspects of the output for this plot.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Actually one can rather easily use the same loop in an `axis`, and thus access all the pgfplots goodies. Note, though, that I am definitely not claiming that this is the answer to the question "pgfplots: Best way to draw a “patchwork” diagram", i.e. I am not saying that this is the best possible way, yet it is one way, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You mentioned `matrix plot` in your first comment. I assume that the `matrix plot` approach was not successful, right?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner A more experienced user may make it work. The fact that I was not able to do so does not mean much.

Comment: Just FYI, I got an alternative approach (https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1518). But it seems that your evaluation stands (= is still correct): It's a tough problem with `pgfplots`.